# MYSQL - UPDATE/INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make an `UPDATE` statement with an `INNER JOIN` in `(MY)SQL`. I already took examples and edited the table names and table columns to mine. But my MYSQL still keep giving me an error (#1064).

**ERROR**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM favorites INNER JOIN images ON favorites.image_id = images.id W' at line 5

**SQL**

```
UPDATE
  favorites
SET
  favorites.archive = 1
FROM
  favorites
INNER JOIN
  images
ON
  favorites.image_id = images.id
WHERE
  favorites.user_id = '1'
```

Thanks in advance in helping me out on this one.

Kind regards,

Comment: Please see the other question, or check [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should to the trick for you.

```
UPDATE favorites 
INNER JOIN images ON favorites.image_id= images.id
SET favorites.archive = 1 
WHERE favorites.user_id = '1';
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Update`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) syntax is different in MySQL. You cannot use `From` clause inside an Update statement.

It is like:

```
Update (all the tables with join relationships if any) 
Set (field = value/expression) 
Where (all the conditions)
```

Try the following query instead:

```
UPDATE
  favorites 
INNER JOIN
  images
ON
  favorites.image_id = images.id
SET
  favorites.archive = 1
WHERE
  favorites.user_id = '1'
```

---

Full [syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) is:

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
    SET assignment_list
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]

value:
    {expr | DEFAULT}

assignment:
    col_name = value

assignment_list:
    assignment [, assignment] ...
```